# How to make calculations on Measure with groupby by column?

Tags: function, powerbi, dax

I have my "Share" calculated based on other columns, and now I want to Group By my "Share" based on "months" (Column : Average ShareByMonth
)

Tried the below code but didn't seem working.
I want data something to look like this :

```
GroupShare_By_month = 
VAR month_var = Table1[Month] (Not allowing me to add column to variable)
VAR Share1 = CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Table1[Share] ),
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Month] = month_var )
                )
Return Share1
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !!

```
Month   ProdSales   MktSales    Share   Average ShareByMonth    
  M1        15       105        0.14    2.67    
  M1        20       90         0.22    2.67    
  M1        25       105        0.24    2.67    
  M1        30       105        0.29    2.67    
  M1        32       110        0.29    2.67     
  M1        35       110        0.32    2.67    sum of share for M1
  M1        65       195        0.33    2.67    
  M1        43       110        0.39    2.67    
  M1        40       90         0.44    2.67    
  M2        10       115        0.09    2.69    
  M2        25       115        0.22    2.69    
  M2        30       120        0.25    2.69    
  M2        35       115        0.30    2.69    
  M2        90       290        0.31    2.69    
  M2        40       120        0.33    2.69    sum of share for M2
  M2        55       145        0.38    2.69    
  M2        45       115        0.39    2.69    
  M2        50       120        0.42    2.69
```

Answer (score 0):

`Table1[Month]` returns a column, not a single value.

Try

```
VAR month_var = VALUES ( Table1[Month] )
```

or

```
VAR month_var = FIRSTNONBLANK ( Table1[Month], 1 )
```

Comment: So I tried this:
1. With VALUES the visuals are breaking,
2. With FIRSTNONBLANK the data is coming similar to Share Column and not the expected column(Avg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
GroupShare_By_month = CALCULATE( sum(Table1[Share]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[Month]))
```